# How to recursively build nested json/hash pairs in ruby?

Tags: json, ruby, hash, tree, binary-tree

I have a list of ruby hash objects(I turn them into json at the end) I need to turn into nested pairs in the order the objects appear in the list.  So, if I had

```
arry =[  {:name => "joe"},  {:type => "normal"}, {:animal => "dog"},  {:age => 5}, {a: 1}, {b: 2}, {c: 3}, {d: 4}]
```

I need to transform it into:

```
{:first => 
         {:first => {:first => {:name => "joe"},
                     :second => {:type => "normal"}},
         :second => {:first => {:animal => "dog"},
                     :second => {:age => 5}}
         }, 
:second =>
         {:first => {:first => {a: 1},
                     :second => {b: 2}},
         :second => {:first => {c: 3},
                     :second => {d: 4}}}
```

This could be nested as deeply as needed by the length of the input list.

I'm totally blanking on how I could do this recursively.  It's sort of like a balanced binary tree where the data is only on the leaves.  I can't seem to find any algorithms that just do that specifically. I also read about B+ trees but that isn't binary and balanced.

As usual I feel like I'm missing something simple and obvious. Maybe there's some kind of built in ruby/json functionality I'm missing?

Comment: What is your end goal in doing this? There doesn't seem to be a real correlation between input an output. When do you decide that something belongs in the outer `:first` or `:second`?

Comment: I suggest you edit to surround the four hash elements with `arr = [` and `]` (and `[` and `]` for output), both to make them proper Ruby objects and also so that, in providing answers, readers could refer to the array `arr`.

Comment: Please show what the output would be if there were four more hashes, say `{a: 1}` and `{b: 2}`, `{c: 3}` and `{d: 4}`.

Comment: Yes, that helps. Will the number of hashes always be a power of 2? Also, one of the reasons I suggested you show the input as an array of hashes is that you'll probably get downvotes if you don't.  I was wrong about the output being an array.

Comment: @JustinWood Someone else at work created this JSON schema for something that is pretty much set in stone because several systems in the company use it. Not just the one I work on. Another person created a system that outputs in one long array that I need to do some filtering on to see which elements I need to take. I also need to add some data from other classes.  I need to take his output and convert it into this highly restrictive JSON schema.

Comment: @CarySwoveland No, if there were to be 5 objects, for example, I would have two pairs of 'leaves' and then the extra one would be coupled with them. (((first second) (first second)) singleton)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that like this (note that I added an element `{e: 5}` so that the number of hashes would not be a power of two):

```
arr= [{   name: "joe"    },
      {   type: "normal" },
      { animal: "dog"    },
      {    age: 5        },
      {      a: 1        },
      {      b: 2        },
      {      c: 3        },
      {      d: 4        },
      {      e: 5        }]

def hashify(arr)
  return arr.first if arr.size == 1
  half = (arr.size+1)/2
  { first: hashify(arr[0,half]) }.merge(second: hashify(arr[half..-1]))
end

hashify(arr)
  #=> { :first=>
  #       { :first=>
  #           { :first=>{ :first=>
  #                         { :name=>"joe" }, :second=>{ :type=>"normal" }
  #                     },
  #             :second=> { :animal=>"dog" }
  #           },
  #         :second=>
  #           { :first=>{:age=>5}, :second=>{:a=>1} }
  #      },
  #    :second=>
  #      { :first=>
  #          { :first=>
  #              { :b=>2 }, :second=>{ :c=>3 } },
  #        :second=>
  #          { :first=>{ :d=>4 }, :second=>{ :e=>5 } }
  #      }
  #   }
```

Comment: Omg, that's amazing. I did just try it with 3 objects and it _seems_ to be working. Though I'm not running on much sleep today.

Comment: On second thought it seems to prefer n^2 -1 length input

Comment: It should be OK now, but let me know if there's a problem.

Comment: I think it works pretty well! Working on ironing out the details before I start testing all my allowable input. This was much simpler than my thought process of writing a whole balanced binary tree class. Thanks so much.